# How to collect multiple images before and after a certain character with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

what i'm actually trying to do is to download, store and recognize which images are before the " + " and which are after that simbol.

Moreover the images that i'm trying to download and store are dynamics, meaning that the numbers of src that are before and after the " + " can change.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL8Au.png) This is the HTML in question.

I'm actually able to download all the images that are inside that h3 but in this way i cannot recognize what are the images that are before the + simbol.

Anyone who has any idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: Share the code what you have tried. Also, edit the question and share the HTML in the form of text rather than image.

Comment: that may get tricky... I think you can get all the inside here by getting the "innerHTML" attribute of the <h3> and then split by the " + ".  (elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");) But from there you'll have to parse each bit.  The problem is you have a text node there, and inside you have element nodes.  An html parser like BeautifulSoup may help.

Comment: Another option might be to get the position of each <img> element and compare.

Comment: For your information: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I've achieved the solution pointing to the " + " simbol and then searching for the images before and after that simbol using the preceding-sibling and following-sibling. Sorry for the image instead of the code.

Comment: you should post your code as the answer. (you can answer your own questions here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this searching for the " + " simbol and then from there search all the images that are before and after using the 'preceding-sibling' and 'following-sibling'.

```
images_before_plus = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3/text()[2]/preceding-sibling::img")
images_after_plus = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3/text()[2]/following-sibling::img")
```

Hope this could help someone else.

Comment: very nice... the 2nd text node!  I wasn't sure you could traverse that.